# Commutators involving $\Box$ and $\Box^{-1}$

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

How to determine the followings:

$$[\Box,\frac{1}{\Box}]\mathcal{O}=?$$

$$[\nabla,\frac{1}{\nabla}]\mathcal{O}=?$$

$$[\nabla^2,\frac{1}{\nabla^2}]\mathcal{O}=?$$

$$[\partial^{2}_{r},\frac{1}{\partial^{2}_{r}}]\mathcal{O}=?$$

Note: In the case of $\Box$ we know they do NOT commute. But is this also true for partial derivative case? We know in some very specific form of $\mathcal{O}$ they do commute, but generally it seems they do not?

How one define $\Box^{-1}$,$\nabla^{-1}$ and etc in terms of integral? What would be the boundaries of the integral?

and $\mathcal{O}$ is an operator in general (one can define between scalar, vector, tensor) (the easiest is scalar of course).

Comment: i think transforming to fourier space would be a good idea here

Comment: Yes $\Box$ is D'Alembert operator @mvw and yes 1/A is inverse operator

Comment: But $[A, A^{-1}] = 0$ in general.

Comment: @mvw That is not always true. For my first example definiton (taking $u_h=0$) of $\square^{-1}$ we have $[\square,\square^{-1}] = 1 - \square$

Comment: I guess this will depend on how you define the inverse. For $\square$ one possible way to do this is to define $\square^{-1}U(x) \equiv u_{\rm h}(x) + \int d^3y G(x,y)U(y)$ where $u_h$ is any function satisfying $\square u_h = 0$ and $G(x,y)$ is any Greens function to $\square$. Another way to do it to define $\square^{-1}U = -\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{k^2}\mathcal{F}[U]\right]$

Comment: Indeed mostly =0 but not always...

Comment: I would have expected $[A, A^{-1}] = A A^{-1} - A^{-1} A = E - E = 0$, just by definition of an inverse as being both a left- and right- inverse. I seem to miss something, so I would be glad for a counter example.

Comment: @mvw When you add "being both left and right inverse" it becomes correct. In many application (particulary in physics where I guess this is coming from) one does only need a left or a right inverse. The first definition I stated above is one such example that is very commonly used. Another thing is that the inverse might not be uniquely defined especially for integral/differential operators, ref. $[\int ,\frac{d}{dx}]$.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Moreover you should think of an inverse derivative as an integral so it does not follow the normal inverse which you wrote indeed. @mvw

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162958/2451 and http://mathoverflow.net/q/195503/13917

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the integral:

As $\Box = \partial_\mu \partial^\mu$ and $\nabla = \partial_k \partial^k$ I would expect the usual Fourier transform $i \partial^\mu = p^\mu$ to map the differential operators to algebraic expressions which can be inverted and back-transformed.